# Regex to get only first character in php

Tags: php, regex

How to get the only first character of string?

```
^1##2##3^1##22##33^1##22##333^1##2##444
```

**OUTPUT:**
1

If string is :

```
 ^71##2##3^1##22##33^71##22##333^71##2##444
```

**OUTPUT:**

71

Want to getch only 1 which in between ^ and ##.

Comment: edited above. please check

Comment: Something like [`^\W*\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/hz4erf/2/) ? Your question remains a bit unclear and you'd likely need to provide more examples or tell us what you mean by "character".

Comment: Yes, Thanks!!!!

Comment: Or `preg_match('~\d+~', $s, $m)` and then `$m[0]`.

Comment: Did you got your answer?

Comment: Yeah, I got an answer and @WiktorStribiżew answer is simplest one and working. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I Checked from [this post](http://www.justin-cook.com/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/)  for get the string from two strings:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini === false) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = '^71##2##3^1##22##33^71##22##333^71##2##444';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '^', '##');

echo $parsed; // (result = 71)
```

Output will be 71 because this function returns first match value...

Comment: I'll advise you to always use `===` when comparing from a strpos. Meaning `if ($ini == 0) return '';` Should be `if ($ini === flase) return '';` beacuse strpos will return false if not found, and false == 0. But false !== 0.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I Referred from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php  and updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the first occurance of a character that is prefixed by a `^` and followed by two hashes:

```
/\^([^\^#]+?)##/
```

This does the following:

1. `\^` finds a `^` character. It needs to be escaped, because `^` is a special char in regex.
2. `([^\^#]+?)##` finds the shortest characters, that are not `^` or `#` itself and are followed by two hashes. If the input `^###` should return `#`, because it is a charater that is prefixed by a `^` and followed by two hashes, just remove the `#` from `[^\^#]` to match it as well.